# XML Node Update with Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a Table with a XML Column. Below is the Sample Data of the XML Column

```
         <ColItem>
             <Item>
                <Name>ItemA</Name>
                <Price>100</Price>
             </Item>
             <Item>
                <Name>ItemB</Name>
                <Price>200</Price>
             </Item>
             <Item>
                <Name>ItemC</Name>
                <Price>300</Price>
             </Item>
        </ColItem>
```

I want to Update 'ItemA' with 'ItemNewA' in the  Node. This should be checked and updated for all rows which has the Item 'ItemA'.

### Pseudo Query

Update Tbl
Set XmlCol.Modify('ItemA') with 'ItemNewA'
Where XMLCol.Has('ItemA')

What should be the actual query to achive this in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server [XML Data Modification Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx) to update an XML column, specifically using [`replace value of`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx) command. Then for the where clause, use XML method [`exist()=1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) :

```
UPDATE Tbl 
SET XmlCol.modify('replace value of (/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.="ItemA"])[1] with "ItemNewA"')
WHERE XmlCol.exist('/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.="ItemA"]')=1
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10c21/7)</kbd>**

**UPDATE :**

This is an example of using SQL Variable in the XPath/XQuery :

```
DECLARE @old VARCHAR(10) = 'ItemA'
DECLARE @new VARCHAR(10) = 'ItemNewA'

UPDATE Tbl 
SET XmlCol.modify('
    replace value of (/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.=sql:variable("@old")])[1] 
    with sql:variable("@new")
')
WHERE XmlCol.exist('/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.=sql:variable("@old")]')=1;
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10c21/12)</kbd>**

Comment: ItemA and ItemNewA comes from a variable. So when i try this: 
                     UPDATE Tbl 
                  SET XmlCol.modify('replace value of                                     (/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.="' +  var1 + '"])[1] with "' + var2 + '"')
           WHERE XmlCol.exist('/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.="' + var1 + '"]')=1;

This gives the error:
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "exist" must be a string literal.

Comment: Is this correct

Declare var1 nvarchar(200) = 'ItemA'
Declare var2 nvarchar(200) = 'ItemNewA'

UPDATE Tbl 
SET XmlCol.modify('replace value of (/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.="{ sql:variable("var1") }"])[1] with "{ sql:variable("var2") }"')
WHERE XmlCol.exist('/ColItem/Item/Name/text()[.= "{ sql:variable("var1") }"]')=1;

Comment: @user2561997 I understand that sample usage scenario given in the MSDN documentation is a bit different. Check **update** section for how to use `sql:variable()` in this question context

Comment: is it possible to make this case insensitive? Should i user lower/upper here in my where clause variable?

Comment: @user2561997 It is possible but using different approach (not using `exist()`). I'd suggest to post another question for that.